# Issue faced on IOS6

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-lion, ios6

I have recently updated with ios6. After that when I am connecting my device Xcode is not finding it, and it is saying like mismatch in version, I am using Mac 10.7.3. Can I use the same version to debug on device? Any idea ???

thanks

Comment: Have you upgraded to Xcode 4.5?  If not, use the App Store.app to do so.

Comment: @NedDeily I'm using 4.3.3 now, Is it possible to work on the same version?

Comment: or Can I update only Xcode without upgrading to Mountain lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You updated your device but not Xcode, to use your iOS 6.0 device for development with Xcode, you require Xcode 4.5, you should check on the Mac App Store and update your Xcode.

Xcode 4.5 will run on both Lion and Mountain Lion. However, on Lion you will also be able to make use of the iOS 4.3 simulator, whereas on Mountain Lion you can't... Just good to know.